# Show $\forall\varepsilon>0\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\#\{\text{positive divisors of n}\}}{n^\varepsilon}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Show that $\forall\varepsilon>0,$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\#\{\text{positive divisors of  n}\}}{n^\varepsilon}=0$$

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time, but I'm really stuck I have totally no idea where to start.
I tried replacing $\varepsilon$ by $\frac{1}{k}$ where $k$ is a natural number, and show the statement is true for all $k$ by induction, but I haven't succeeded and it doesn't seem promising.

If you give me any advice or comment, I would greatly appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: How many positive divisors has an integer n at most? What if $n=2^r$?

Comment: You can use this math overflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133306/best-upper-bound-on-the-number-of-divisors-of-n-that-are-larger-than-n

Comment: Thank you, @AdLibitum. If $n=2^r$, I think the # of positive divisors is $r+1$. Can we say for general $n$, if $2^{r-1}<n\leq2^r$, the # of positive divisors is at most $r+1$?

Comment: Look at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/

Comment: Take a look at Apostol's *Introduction to analytic number theory*, pages 294-296. It addresses your concerns.

Comment: @AdLibitum Powers of $2$ don't maximize divisor count, relative to the size of the integer. Primorials behave stronger.  For example, $32$ only has $6$ divisors, but $30=2\cdot3\cdot5$ has $8$. And even primorials don't maximize divisor count. If you explore the ratio of divisor count to integer size, the highest values come from numbers that are built like primorials, but occasionally start throwing in more small primes rather than the next biggest prime.

Comment: @Alice To answer your question in the comment, no. See my comment above, where $30$ has $8$ divisors but is sandwiched between $2^4$ and $2^5$.

Comment: [This sequence from OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002182) may be of general interest.

Comment: @Batman Thank you for the information!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you. This is detailed.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Thank you. I will.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I know that. I mentioned powers of 2 (or of any prime $p$) just as an example to acquire familiarity with the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem falls out from the following fact.

\begin{equation}
e^{O(\frac{log(n)}{loglog(n)})}=d(n)
\end{equation}

So,

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{d(n)}{n^\epsilon}=\frac{e^{\frac{Clog(n)}{loglog(n)}}}{n^\epsilon}
\end{equation}
For some constant C.

Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{Clog(n)}{loglog(n)}}}{n^\epsilon}=\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{n^\frac{C}{loglog(n)}}{n^\epsilon}=\lim_{n->\infty}n^{\frac{C}{loglog(n)}-\epsilon}
\end{equation}

You can add a nice proof regarding epsilon and deltas to show from here that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{C}{loglog(n)}-\epsilon=-\epsilon\\and\\
\lim_{n->\infty}n^{-\epsilon}=0\\
implies\\
\lim_{n->\infty}n^{\frac{C}{loglog(n)}-\epsilon}=0
\end{equation}

This completes our proof.  Many websites have the first point written and I believe you may be able to find out more about it from other stack exchange posts.

Comment: If you want, I can give you a very VERY trivial proof for when  epsilon is larger than 1/2 if this proof uses information that is unknown to you.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a plot of demonstration I have come up with, although I am not sure about its formality.

The limit we aim to prove is equivalent to prove that, if we are given primes $p_i ;  i\in [N]$, then $$\lim_{\alpha_i \to \infty \text{ for some i}} \frac{\prod_{i \in [N]}(\alpha_i + 1)}{\prod_{i \in [N]}p_i^{\alpha_i e}}= 0$$, where we have used that the number of divisors of the number $n = \prod_{i \in [N]}{p_i}^{\alpha_i}$ equals $\prod_{i \in [N]}(\alpha_i + 1)$.

If you are able to prove the last statement formally, I guess you will not have problems to finish this demonstration.